# adding nodes to MAAS server?. .

Tags: maas

we have installed MAAS on one system. we want to add nodes to the MAAS server what is the good way to do it?.  can u give us a link or a step by step instructions to do the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see http://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/nodes.html.

(this text is here to make up the ridiculous required minimum character count)